# Add value labels (not percentages) to donut chart - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, donut-chart

I would like to display actual value labels instead of %age values for a donut chart. The following code generates a pretty nice donut chart, but the displayed values are for %ages but not their actual values.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#create labels and values for pie/donut plot
labels = 'ms', 'ps'
sizes = [1851, 2230]

#create center white circle
centre_circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.7, color='white')

#create pie chat
plt.pie(sizes, labels= labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',pctdistance = 1.25,startangle=90,
        labeldistance=.8, colors = ["tab:blue", "tab:orange"])
plt.axis('equal')
plt.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)

#Display
plt.show();
```

My output is shown below.

[image]

Can somebody guide me on how to show the actual values (1851, 2230) and not their percentage values on this plot? Alternatively, display both the %ages and their actual corresponding values (i.e., 1851, 45.4% and 2230, 54.6%)?

Comment: Use the values as labels and remove the `autopct` options.

Comment: The following did not work. Did I misunderstand your comment?                                                                                                                       plt.pie(sizes, labels= labels, values = [1851, 2230],startangle=90,
        labeldistance=.8, colors = ["tab:blue", "tab:orange"])

Comment: Make `labels = [f'{s} ({s*100/sum(sizes):%.2f})' for s in sizes]`.

Comment: Check my answer. It is a improved version and there is no need for the internal white circle hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing my comments, try this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


labels = 'ms', 'ps'
sizes = 1851, 2230
pcts = [f'{s} {l}\n({s*100/sum(sizes):.2f}%)' for s,l in zip(sizes, labels)]
width = 0.35

_, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('equal')

pie, _ = ax.pie(
    sizes,
    startangle=90,
    labels=pcts,
#    labeldistance=.8,
#    rotatelabels=True,
    colors = ["tab:blue", "tab:orange"]
)

plt.setp(pie, width=width, edgecolor='white')

plt.show()
```

And here is the output of the code snippet above:

[image: Chart]

Comment: Beautiful donut :) Thank you accdias!